# What happened to libapache2-mod-macro in Xenial?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

Our server stack is quite reliant on the Macro mods for Apache.

In previous distros (i.e. Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, 14.04), that functionality came in the libapache2-mod-macro package.

However this package has disappeared from Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04). Does anyone know what happened to it? Did it moved or subsumed into a different package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, it was only a transitional package.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libapache2-mod-macro

Comment: Does that mean it got merged into Apache core, or something like that? So does that page mean it's now part of the apache-bin package?

Comment: yes, according to this page.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 mod_macro should be installed with apache2 already.

Type

```
sudo a2enmod macro
```

to active it